# Filter dropdown list on other filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, filter, drop-down-menu

Hey guys I know it had been discussed so much but I still don't get it working.

What I need is to filter a gridview by a few dropdown lists and the main idea is to "continue" filtering the gridview. I mean, when I select value from ddl1, then the ddl2 is filtered according to the selected value in ddl1.

Also called cascading dropdown list but I don't want to (can not) use Ajax Control Toolkit...

Any other solutions to that? Maybe the method 
`protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(...)` can do this but I don't know how to use it.

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `ddl1` has `the true autopostback` `ddl2` can easily be build according to `ddl1`'s `SelectedValue` in `ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged` with `code`.

Comment: yeah exactly but I can't figure out the code needed yet..

Comment: Pepys I am sorry but this is not a place to ask for code this is a place to ask for help when the code you wrote has problems which you can't solve.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the below. It is just to give you an idea...

```
DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(...){
// get the ddl1 selected value
// filter the datasource used by dropdownlist2
// databind DropDownList2 
}

DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(...){
    // get the ddl1 selected value 
    // get the ddl2 selected value 
    // filter the datasource used by GridView(using the DropDownList selected values)
    // databind GridView 
}
```

Comment: that's more like it ;)
I have to try this but later
Thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Jquery to fill cascaded dropdownlists. Add this script to your webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

$("#<%= ddlState.ClientID %>").change(function () {

```
var sourceddl = "<%= ddlState.ClientID %>";
var stateid = $("#<%= ddlState.ClientID %> option:selected").val();
var Stateid = { Stateid: stateid };

$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'YourCodeBehind.aspx/GetCounties',
                data: JSON.stringify(Stateid),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {                       
                          if (data.d) { 
                          var options = [];                     
                          if (result.d) {
                          for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
                               options.push('<option value="',
                                              result.d[i].countyID, '">',
                                              result.d[i].countyName, '</option>');
                            }

                            $("#<%= ddlCounty.ClientID %>").html(options.join(''));
                        }                        
                     }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error! Try again...");
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

here is the webmethod which is in the same codebehind.

```
[WebMethod]
public static County[] GetCounties(int Stateid)
{
    County[] countiesArr = StatesCountyModel.GetCountyForState(Stateid).ToArray();
    return countiesArr;     
}
```

If you are new to Jquery. go through the http://Jquery.com to understand how to use it.

Hope it helps.

Praveen

Comment: No problems! you can use our old friend javascript here. see this http://forums.asp.net/t/1413113.aspx

Comment: Hehe this seems pretty cool... but I don't really understand it. Like where is the database connection, columns, etc etc... 
Is this working with Gridview since this is the main idea - to get the gridview fitered :? 
p.s sorry for the stupid questions but it's java script :)

Comment: that's right. its old plain javascript infact that's how Ajax works. and if you see a line the article.                                   // Send the request
 xmlHttp.open("GET", "GetProducts.aspx?CategoryID=" + pCatID, true);       This .aspx page will have the logic and return you the results as an xml schema. you can loop through it and fill your child dropdownlist.

Comment: thanks dude but I really don't understand the idea.. Can you have a look at the code i added above,please :)
Thanks